# Agrupar por mes sumando un campo MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta consulta `mysql` que solo me debería dar la suma de 2 campos agrupados por mes de todos los años que estén registrados en la base.

Funciona parcialmente(solo me suma las filas del mes hasta el día 12 inclusive).

Codigo SQL:

```
SELECT fecha ,
SUM(entrante) AS credito,
SUM(saliente) AS debito
FROM libro
GROUP by YEAR(fecha),MONTH(fecha)
ORDER BY fecha
```

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y MYSQL y no se como resolver este dilema.

---

Gracias  ManucoBianco pero me da este error

[image: Error en consulta]

Comment: Proba sin agrupar por month. Es de ahi q te retorna solo 12 resultados.

Comment: si lo pense, pero quiero sumar todos los registros por mes año a año.... ¿como hago?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de la tabla y otro del resultado que quieres obtener por favor.

Answer (score 3):

bueno creo que esto me servira:

```
SELECT fecha ,
SUM(entrante) AS credito,
SUM(saliente) AS debito
FROM libro
WHERE YEAR(fecha)='2017'
GROUP by MONTH(fecha)
```

haciendo un bucle de todos los años tengo lo que deseo:

resultado de la consulta:

```
fecha   credito     debito  
2017-01-04  62370   43502
2017-02-06  36360   17750
2017-03-06  26110   10268
2017-04-03  34730   30483
2017-05-09  68620   35582
2017-06-05  45780   34742
2017-07-05  53460   28368
2017-08-01  21220   17950
2017-09-02  35440   610
2017-10-02  29210   10276
2017-11-01  96110   47370
2017-12-02  98720   58362
```

me suma todos los dias.

si hay una forma de hacerlo en una sola consulta para todos los años que esten almacenados por favor diganme como........ para aprender!!! ;)

Comment: ¿se puede poner un alias para que muestre el mes en la columna fecha?..... claro que puedo hacer un echo date("m", strtotime($row['fecha'])); solo quiero saber si es posible hacerlo en la consulta

Comment: Bueno justo esto tenía pensado pero es muy poco eficiente.